# Converting XML elements to XML attributes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

We have a current system that outputs an XML file which is in the following format:

```
<INVENTORY>
   <ITEM>
      <SERIALNUMBER>something</SERIALNUMBER>
      <LOCATION>something</LOCATION>
      <BARCODE>something</BARCODE>
   </ITEM>
</INVENTORY>
```

I need to use this data to load into the standard .NET 2.0 grid. But the grid needs the XML to be in the following format:

```
<INVENTORY>
   <ITEM serialNumber="something" location="something" barcode="something">
   </ITEM>
</INVENTORY>
```

i.e. the child nodes of item need to be converted into attributes of the item node.

Does someone know how this can be done using XSLT?

Comment: Please read the markup documentation, you need 4 spaces or a tab so that SO recognises code.

Comment: The answer you accepted doesn't produce the result you want!!!  One attribute name must be "serialNumber", the accepted solution produces "serialnumber". Next time do not mislead the people who spend their time to help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="INVENTORY">
    <INVENTORY>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </INVENTORY>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ITEM">
    <ITEM>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </ITEM>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 4):

These two templates should do it:-

```
<xsl:template match="ITEM">
   <ITEM serialNumber="{SERIALNUMBER}" location="{LOCATION}" barcode="{BARCODE}" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="INVENTORY">
   <INVENTORY>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </INVENTORY>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Here is probably the simplest solution** that will convert any children-elements of `ITEM` to its attributes and will reproduce everything else as is, while converting the element names to any desired attribute names:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<!--                                              --> 
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vrtfNameMapping">
    <item name="SERIALNUMBER" newName="serialNumber"/>
    <item name="LOCATION" newName="location"/>
    <item name="BARCODE" newName="barcode"/>
  </xsl:variable>
 <!--                                              --> 
  <xsl:variable name="vNameMapping" select=
  "document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='vrtfNameMapping']"/>
<!--                                              --> 

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
<!--                                              --> 
  <xsl:template match="ITEM/*">
    <xsl:attribute name=
     "{$vNameMapping/*[@name=name(current())]/@newName}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when the above transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<INVENTORY>
    <ITEM>
        <SERIALNUMBER>something</SERIALNUMBER>
        <LOCATION>something</LOCATION>
        <BARCODE>something</BARCODE>
    </ITEM>
</INVENTORY>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<INVENTORY>
   <ITEM serialNumber="something" location="something" barcode="something"/>
</INVENTORY>
```

**Do note** the following:

1. The use of the [**identity rule**](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)
2. The use of [**`<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-strip-space)
3. The use of the variable **`vrtfNameMapping`** without any `xxx:node-set()` extension function.
4. The fact that we handle any mapping between a name and a newName, not only simple lower-casing.

Comment: Doesn't look like this transformation works. It is not producing any result. Just this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<INVENTORY>
   <ITEM />
</INVENTORY>

Comment: @Mark, This means you either have a buggy XSLT processor, or you haven't copied and pasted exactly the XML document and the transformation. I just re-executed the transformation -- the same result is produced with several XSLT processors

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do it:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//ITEM">
    <xsl:element name="ITEM">
      <xsl:attribute name="serialNumber">
        <xsl:value-of select="SERIALNUMBER"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="location">
        <xsl:value-of select="LOCATION"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="barcode">
        <xsl:value-of select="BARCODE"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Or using David's shortcut:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ITEM">
  <ITEM serialNumber="{SERIALNUMBER}" location="{LOCATION}" barcode="{BARCODE}"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your source looks like this:

```
<row><a>1</a><b>2</b></row>
```

and you want it to look like this:

```
<row a="1" b="2" />
```

then this XSLT should work:

```
<xsl:template match="row">
    <row a="{a}" b="{b}" />
</xsl:template>
```