# Code provided to convert xml tags to attributes. Please explain. I'm a newbie

Tags: c#, xml

I need to convert xml tags to attributes so the following code loops through and does that BUT I'm a newbie. Just downloaded Visual Studio. I am used to actionscript so it's similar. However, I don't know how to paste in the code to make it work.

[Converting XML nodes into attributes using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322677/converting-xml-nodes-into-attributes-using-c-sharp)

This is what I have so far. I pressed on new c# project and new class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        foreach (XElement el in root.Elements()) { 
        root.Add(new XAttribute(el.Name, (string)el)); }
        root.Elements().Remove(); 
        Console.WriteLine(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to Google some more stuff. Start with:
[Creating a console application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) and 
[Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you are asking here.

If you want to load an [XDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from an XML file, use [`XDocument.Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If you want to load an `XDocument` from a string containing XML, use [`XDocument.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to promote the child elements of an `XElement` to be attributes of that element, you need to be aware that, unlike elements, duplicated attribute names are disallowed by the XML standard.  You might also want to skip elements that contain nested child elements.  If you don't, be aware that [`(string)el`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) behaves as follows:

> If the XElement has children, the concatenated string value of all of the element's text and descendant's text is returned.

That being said, the following promotes child elements to attributes, concatenating the values of identically named elements but doing nothing if there is already an attribute with the element's name:

```
    public static void PromoteChildElementsToAttributes(XElement element)
    {
        foreach (var group in element.Elements().GroupBy(el => el.Name))
        {
            // Remove if you don't want this check.
            if (element.Elements().Any())
            {
                //Uncomment if you want to skip elements with children.
                //continue;
            }
            if (element.Attribute(group.Key) != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Cannot add duplicate attribute " + element.Attribute(group.Key));
                continue;
            }
            var value = group.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, el) => sb.Append((string)el)).ToString();
            element.Add(new XAttribute(group.Key, value));
            foreach (var el in group)
                el.Remove();
        }
    }
```

And you could call it like:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
PromoteChildElementsToAttributes(doc.Root)
```