# XML transformation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a current XML file as shown below.

```
<INVOICES>
  <INVOICE>
    <HEADER>
        <DocumentID>001500113139_1260538</DocumentID>
        <DocumentID>001500113138_1262778</DocumentID>
        <DocumentID>001500113137_1262762</DocumentID>
        <DocumentID>001500113136_1260522</DocumentID>               
    </HEADER>
  </INVOICE>
</INVOICES>
```

This has to be transformed to the below format  using XSLT.

```
<Batches>
    <Batch ID="20141119">
      <Documents>
        <Document ID= 001500113139_1260538 />
        <Document ID= 001500113138_1262778 />
        <Document ID= 001500113137_1262762 />
        <Document ID= 001500113136_1260522 />
      </Documents>
    </Batch>
</Batches>
```

How to map the Xml elements to attributes. Could anyone suggest please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This link might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655411/converting-xml-elements-to-xml-attributes-using-xslt)

Comment: Show us what you have so far, and let us know where you got stuck. By the way, your output format is invalid, since the `ID` attributes are not quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Batches>
      <Batch ID="20141119">
        <xsl:for-each select="//DocumentID">
          <Document>
            <xsl:attribute name="ID">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </Document>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Batch>
    </Batches>
  </xsl:template>
```