# Reformat XML from tag to proprty and name

Tags: java, xml

Is anyone knows a tool or a `jar` that can reformat XML, for example:

```
<job>
    <id>7562882</id>
    <title>Techniker im Unterhalt (m/w) in Murten</title>
    <deleted>false</deleted>
</job>
```

To:

```
<job>
<property name="id">7562882</property>
  <property name="title">Techniker im Unterhalt (m/w) in Murten</property>
 <property name="deleted">false</property>
</job>
```

and `child nodes` from:

```
<company>
        <id>40057210</id>
        <name>Roland Murten AG</name>
</company>
```

to

```
 <property name="company-id">40057210</property>
 <property name="company-name">Roland Murten AG</property>
```

any solution in java will be great, but because it is not a simple thing to do I will use solution in any OO.
Thanks.
I dont want to add the value as part of the tag, only to reformat.

Comment: How about consider using xslt to transform in the desired format?

Comment: There's no tool that can do that out of the box. You have to write some code, e.g. Java using StAX, or maybe write an XSLT transformation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting XML elements to XML attributes using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655411/converting-xml-elements-to-xml-attributes-using-xslt)

Comment: Yes, I guessed so, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSLT transformation will do it:

```java
private static void transform(String xml) throws TransformerException {
    String xslt = "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">\n" +
                  "  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\"/>\n" +
                  // Transform child elements of <job>
                  "  <xsl:template match=\"job/*\">\n" +
                  "    <property name=\"{local-name(.)}\"><xsl:value-of select=\".\"/></property>\n" +
                  "  </xsl:template>\n" +
                  // Remove <company>, but transform children
                  "  <xsl:template match=\"company\">\n" +
                  "    <xsl:apply-templates select=\"node()\"/>\n" +
                  "  </xsl:template>\n" +
                  // Transform child elements of <company>
                  "  <xsl:template match=\"company/*\">\n" +
                  "    <property name=\"{local-name(..)}-{local-name(.)}\"><xsl:value-of select=\".\"/></property>\n" +
                  "  </xsl:template>\n" +
                  // Copy all other content unchanged
                  "  <xsl:template match=\"@*|node()\">\n" +
                  "    <xsl:copy>\n" +
                  "      <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*|node()\"/>\n" +
                  "    </xsl:copy>\n" +
                  "  </xsl:template>\n" +
                  "</xsl:stylesheet>\n";
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslt)));
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)),
                          new StreamResult(System.out));
}
```

*Test*

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    transform("<job>\n" +
              "    <id>7562882</id>\n" +
              "    <title>Techniker im Unterhalt (m/w) in Murten</title>\n" +
              "    <deleted>false</deleted>\n" +
              "</job>\n");
    System.out.println();   System.out.println();
    transform("<company>\n" +
              "        <id>40057210</id>\n" +
              "        <name>Roland Murten AG</name>\n" +
              "</company>\n");
}
```

*Output*

```xml
<job>
    <property name="id">7562882</property>
    <property name="title">Techniker im Unterhalt (m/w) in Murten</property>
    <property name="deleted">false</property>
</job>

        <property name="company-id">40057210</property>
        <property name="company-name">Roland Murten AG</property>
```

Comment: First of all thanks!! I will mark your solution as the right one, is it a function for this specific case or a global one?

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas If you look at the XSLT, you'll see that it explicitly names `job` and `company`. All other elements are copied unchanged. Read the XSLT documentation to learn more: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/

Comment: Thanks, I will continue it to the full version.