# Migrate XML element value to attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I've the below xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BLOG blogsiteurl="url">
    <ARTICLES>
        <ARTICLE id="article1">
            <TITLE id="title1">A Sample Article</TITLE>
            <SECT>The First Major Section
                <PARA>This section will introduce a subsection.</PARA>
                    <PARA>This is the text of the subsection.
                    </PARA>
                    <RATING>3.4</RATING>
            </SECT>
        </ARTICLE>
        <ARTICLE id="article2">
            <TITLE id="title2">A Sample Article</TITLE>
            <SECT>The First Major Section
                <PARA>This section will introduce a subsection.</PARA>
                    <PARA>This is the text of the subsection.
                    </PARA>
                    <RATING>4.5</RATING>
            </SECT>
        </ARTICLE>
    </ARTICLES>
</BLOG>
```

and I want to migrate the value of RATING element to one of it's attribute value like given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BLOG blogsiteurl="url">
    <ARTICLES>
        <ARTICLE id="article1">
            <TITLE id="title1">A Sample Article</TITLE>
            <SECT>The First Major Section
                <PARA>This section will introduce a subsection.</PARA>
                    <PARA>This is the text of the subsection.
                    </PARA>
            <RATING value="3.4"></RATING>
            </SECT>
        </ARTICLE>
        <ARTICLE id="article2">
            <TITLE id="title2">A Sample Article</TITLE>
            <SECT>The First Major Section
                <PARA>This section will introduce a subsection.</PARA>
                    <PARA>This is the text of the subsection.
                    </PARA>
            <RATING value="4.5"></RATING>
            </SECT>
        </ARTICLE>
    </ARTICLES>
</BLOG>
```

How can I achieve this using xlst? Is there any other better approach over xslt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting XML elements to XML attributes using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655411/converting-xml-elements-to-xml-attributes-using-xslt)

Comment: Yep, you'll find the solution you're looking for in the post linked above.

Comment: I also need to copy the attribute values of all the tags which won't be copied by the above linked post

Comment: You can use `identity transform` for the same. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks [Aniket V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2209666) it worked.