# How to generate XML using all the columns as attributes and rows as XML tag named <ROW>

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Requirement : Hello, I need to generate a XML out of the results produced by a CTE. Each row should be represented by a new XML tag and all column values are its XML attributes.

Conditions : The Query inside the CTE is dynamic hence the name and number and columns produced by it cannot be known in advance.

For generating the XML I am currently running the query inside CTE and typing each of column names inside XMLATTRIBUTES() function as shown in below example:-

```
with cte as(
select 'john' as name_,
'2021' as dept,
'26' as age
FROM dual
)
SELECT
   XMLELEMENT("ROW", XMLAGG( XMLELEMENT("ROW", XMLATTRIBUTES( name_,dept,age ) ) ) ) 
FROM
   cte;
```

Please suggest a way to include all the columns produced by CTE query without typing all the column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dbms_xmlgen` to generate an XML version of your CTE; the slight trick is create a context on the fly form a ref cursor, using the `cursor()` function:

```
with cte as(
select 'john' as name_,
'2021' as dept,
'26' as age
FROM dual
)
SELECT
   dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(cursor(select * from cte)))
from dual;
```

which generates:

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <NAME_>john</NAME_>
  <DEPT>2021</DEPT>
  <AGE>26</AGE>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Then riffing off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/655463/266304), you can convert the column nodes to attributes:

```
with cte as(
select 'john' as name_,
'2021' as dept,
'26' as age
FROM dual
)
SELECT
   dbms_xmlgen
     .getxmltype(dbms_xmlgen.newcontext(cursor(select * from cte)))
     .transform(xmltype('<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="ROWSET">
    <ROWSET>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ROWSET>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ROW">
    <ROW>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

      </xsl:for-each>
    </ROW>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>'))
from dual;
```

which gives you:

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW NAME_="john" DEPT="2021" AGE="26"></ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

I've left the root node as `rowset` but if you do really want both the root and inner nodes to be called `row` you can just change that in the XLST document. And you can add a `tostringval()` or `toclobval()` call if you don't want the result as an XMLType.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=38f71593e77382e5e098e9039e954c8b)